# Store value in a variable via Knockout loop in html

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to KO, in my html file I am printing a value like this -

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: JSON.parse($parent.options), as: 'option' } -->
    <!-- ko if: option.label === 'AAA' || option.label === 'BBB'  -->
        <dd class="values" data-bind="html: option.value"></dd>
    <!-- /ko -->    
<!-- /ko -->
```

And its working fine . But what I want is, I want assign all values of loop to a variable and want to print after loop. Like we do in php-

```
foreach($data as $key=> $index){
    if($key==0)
        $var = $index['value'];
    else
        $var .= ' '.$index['value'];    
}

echo $var
```

I want to do the same in KO's html file using above KO loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 **[`computed`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)** propertieslike this.

- `parsedOptions` to get the parsed JSON.
- `concatenatedValues` to get the values separated by space using **[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**.

Then loop through `parsedOptions` in the `foreach`. And bind `concatenatedValues` to a `span`

```js
const JSONstring = JSON.stringify([{ label: "AAA", value: 1 },{ label: "BBB", value: 2 },{ label: "CCC", value: 3 }]);

const viewModel = function() {  
  this.options = JSONstring;
  
  this.parsedOptions = ko.computed(() => {
    return JSON.parse(this.options)
  });
  
  this.concatenatedValues = ko.computed(() => {
    return this.parsedOptions().map(a => a.value).join(' ')
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: { data: parsedOptions, as: 'option' } -->
    <!-- ko if: option.label === 'AAA' || option.label === 'BBB'  -->
        <dd class="values" data-bind="html: option.value"></dd>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->

<br> All values:
<span data-bind="text: concatenatedValues"></span>
```